# Console.Write makes Sound

Tags: c#, audio, console, console-application

today I came across something that actually scared me when it happened.

I was reading out a file as an Byte-Array and printed each byte out converted as a char like the following:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
foreach(byte bt in bytes)
{
   Console.Write((char)bt + " ");
}
```

The thing is now, that printing the converted values out to Console actually made a sound in my headset and my general audio-output..

When I then clicked into the console to stop the execution, after a few seconds there was a Windows-Notification-Sound like when you get an update or something like that.

My question now is why this is happening?

Also note that I tested the `File.ReadAllBytes` using a mp4-file first and then with a .zip. With a plain .txt-file it doesnt seem to work.

Also I am using Windows 10.

Comment: weird. maybe because you press any other buttons like ctrl idk. or its IDE debugger? who knows. try running app without IDE debugger, so build and open build folder, and run manually

Comment: Yes, a whole bunch of the ASCII table is control Characters. Like Carriage return. And "BIOS Beep".

Comment: There's a character that emits a beep. You may be writing that accidentally.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character

Comment: You can even get the console to beep inentionally: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep?view=netframework-4.8 | If you just interpret a byte array as characters, there is a 1/256 chance that you will hit any specific character. Including the one that forces the console to make "beep".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I was able to figure out that a beeping-character was actually called out, which caused Windows 10 to do basically infinite beeping-sounds.

I checked for the Hex-Value of 0x07 now before emitting the sound, and it turned out that, after setting a breakpoint, it actually is in the byte-array and when printed it made the sound.

Thanks everyone, I am not cursed after all ;) :)

PS:

I used the german Wiki-Page to get the hex-value:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steuerzeichen

On the English one I couldnt find it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character -- Look at the table on the right side.

Comment: "I checked for the Hex-Value of 0x07 now before emitting the sound, and it turned out that, after setting a breakpoint, it actually is in the byte-array and when printed it made the sound." There is only 256 possible values for ASCII. And if you parse random binary data, there is a chance you will hit any given character by accident.

Comment: @stickybit ah thanks, somehow I skippen through this ^^

Comment: @Christopher yes, I see, It just really suprised me that it was possible to actually send Windows Notifications just by writing to a console